# Taking a string from a user and checking it against a "Password" variable

Tags: string, passwords

I am trying to create a program that takes a string from a user and checks it against a "password" variable. If the password is equal it prints "valid" if not then "invalid"

Here is what I have so far, it looks correct to me, but it apparently isn't.

```
import java.util.*;

class WS6Q5 {
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

    String s =" ";
    int x = 123;


    System.out.println("Please type in the Password");
    s=in.nextLine();


    if (s.length()==x){
        System.out.println("Access Granted");
    }

    else if (s.length()!=x){
        System.out.println("Invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why using `length()` and not `equals()`?

Comment: he expects a password of length 123

Answer (score 0):

As one might expect, `s.length()` gives you the length, in characters, of string `s`. Your variable `x` is set to the integer (not string!) value `123`. So your if-statement is seeing whether x is 123 characters long. Probably not what you want!

1. You probably want x to be a string. `String x = "123"`.
2. You want to compare the *value* of x to the value of s. Look at `String.equals()` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

Comment: thanks for the comment, i have been trying to edit it but it still isn't working, where is it exactly that i am supposed to put in anObject? is it instead of s.length? 

but thank you for explaining the part about s.length, i know now that it counts the length of the characters !

Comment: EDIT: I figured it out, thanks! :D here is the code: 

     `import java.util.*;

    class WS6Q5 {
 public static void main (String[] args){
  Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
  
  String randomtext = "HelloWorld";
  
  System.out.println("Please type in the Password");
  randomtext=in.nextLine();
  
  
  if(randomtext.equals ("HelloWorld")){
   System.out.println("Access Granted");
  }
  
  else {
   System.out.println("Invalid");
  }
 }
    } `